# PDF generated by cups-pdf behave strange

Tags: cups, print-to-pdf

I use [olbat/cupsd](https://hub.docker.com/r/olbat/cupsd) docker image. I created printer with Generic CUPS-PDF Printer (w/ options) driver.

PDF files generated by my printers looks good but when I copy text from generated PDF file and paste it somewhere then gibberish text appears instead of originally copied text. Client printer driver is not responsible for this issue because the same issue occurs when I print from Windows OS and when I print from docker container. E.g. I can execute following commands inside my docker container:

```
echo "Hello" > file.txt
lp -d  myPdfPrinter file.txt
```

Generated PDF looks good, there is "Hello" text when I open PDF file using Foxit PDF reader or Adobe Acrobat Reader. I open it on my host with Windows 10 OS. When I copy "Hello" text and paste somewhere then ✁✂✂✄ is pasted. In addition text searching does not work, Foxit and Adobe can not find "Hello" world in PDF file even though PDF looks properly and I see "Hello" word when I open PDF file in Foxit or Adobe.

How to fix it?

Comment: check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/335848/how-to-copy-paste-text-from-pdf-generated-by-cups-pdf